# Hibernate ManyToMany wtih column child removal

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have Many To Many with additional column. Here realization(getters/setters generated by lombok, removed for clarity):

```
public class User extends BaseEntity {
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user",
        orphanRemoval = true,            
        fetch = FetchType.LAZY
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL,)
   private List<UserEvent> attendeeEvents = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Table(
        name = "UC_USER_EVENT",
        uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"user_id", "event_id"})}
)
public class UserEvent extends BaseEntity {

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "event_id")
    private Event event;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_response_id")
    private UserResponse userResponse;
}

public class Event extends BaseEntity { 
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "event",
            orphanRemoval = true,
            fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<UserEvent> userEvents = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

I want this - when i delete Event, All "UserEvents" connected to it should be removed. And if I delete User, all "UserEvents" should be removed too.

I delete my event(eventRepository is Spring Jpa interface):

```
 eventRepository.delete(event);
```

Then retrieving UserEvents from db:

```
List<UserEvent> userEvents = userEventsId.stream()
.map(id -> entityManager.find(UserEvent.class, id)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

And there is collection with 2 items(this is count of UserEvents), but they all "null".

I can't understand what happening and how to do it right.
I need them deleted and when I check collection there should be 0, instead of 2.

Comment: Why are your many-to-one mappings marked with `CascadeType.ALL`? Should deleting a `UserEvent` also delete the associated `User`?

Comment: Regarding your question, calling `map()` on a stream of two elements without a call to `filter()` results in a stream that, well, still has two elements

Comment: I was sure it's hibernate problem... Thank you! I already removed CascadeType.All on UserEvent, but was totally unaware of map().

Answer (score 1):

The delete says marked for deletion, please try calling flush after deletion, and then find.

I guess find goes to the database, find the two rows, but when trying to instantiate them, find the entities marked for deletion and then you have this strange behaviour.

Recomendation: try to abstract more from the database and use less annotations. Learn the conventions of names for columns and tables (if you need to) and let JPA do its job.

Comment: It was map problem, because collection of Ids was size of 2. And when i used stream().map() it returned collection of size 2 too. But there was 2 nulls. About flush - when i deleting entity - it not needed, but if i update entity - without it update won't work correctly.